# Graphics lags when painting to screen

Tags: java, graphics, paintcomponent, graphics2d, lag

I am loosely following [this persons code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/27197/pong-game-in-java) to make a pong game

However, when I run the program, the screen will either, 1. turn plain white, 2. Turn white and then paint to the screen a couple seconds later, or 3. paint to the screen immediately.

I don't have very much code currently. Why is there sometimes a delay when painting to my frame? how can I fix this? is there a better way to do this?

[Main class]

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main extends JFrame {
public static final int FRAME_WIDTH = 900, FRAME_HEIGHT = 500;
GamePanel game;

public Main() {
    this.setTitle("Pong");
    this.setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    this.setVisible(true);

    game = new GamePanel(this);
    add(game);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main main = new Main();

}

public int getWidth() {
    return FRAME_WIDTH;
}

public int getHeight() {
    return FRAME_HEIGHT;

}

}
```

[Game Panel]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class GamePanel extends JPanel {
private Main main;
private Player player;
private int playerScore = 0;
private int oppScore = 0;

private int yCenter;

public GamePanel(Main main) {
    setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    this.main = main;
    this.yCenter = (main.getHeight() / 2) - 75;
    player = new Player(main, 25, yCenter);

}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.setFont(new Font("Courier", Font.BOLD, 40));
    g.drawString(playerScore + " - " + oppScore, (main.getWidth() / 2) - 75, 50);

    player.draw(g);

}

}
```

[Player Class]

```
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class Player {
private Main main;
private static final int PLAYER_WIDTH = 30, PLAYER_HEIGHT = 125;
private int x, y;

public Player(Main main, int x, int y) {
    this.main = main;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;

}

public void draw(Graphics g) {
    g.fillRect(x, y, PLAYER_WIDTH, PLAYER_HEIGHT);
}

}
```

Comment: call `setVisible(true)` on the JFrame only **after** adding all components to the GUI.

Comment: hmm, that doesn't seem to be doing the trick, there is still a second long delay before the white screen turns black and paints

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels